# Python adds unicode to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, unicode

Im writing a default dict (list) to  a file with :

```
def write_to_file(slack_dict):
    if os.path.exists("slack_dict"):
        print ("slack_dict file already exist, skipping writing")
    else:
        print ("writing slack_dict to file")
        F = open('slack_dict', "w")
        F.write(str(slack_dict).encode('UTF-8'))
        F.close()
```

the slack_dict being written to file is  :

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'djin_acontentmgmt_sample': [{'color': u'blue', 
    'status': 'SUCCESS', 'region': u'virginia', 'env': u'int', 'job_no': '122'}]})
```

How do I remove the unicode strings ? I already have tried `F.write(str(slack_dict).encode('UTF-8'))`

Comment: First, the `u` prefix is not used by Python-3.x. Are you sure your question is about both 3.x and 2.7? Second, you encoded the string as `utf-8`, which makes it a Unicode string. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: If your goal is to save the dictionary to a file for a future use, consider using module `pickle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I do the following, there are no non-ASCII characters in the 'slack_dict' file, since there are no non-ASCII characters in any of the 'Unicode' strings in the dictionary. Everything is stored exactly as shown (e.g., a literal 'u', not a non-ASCII character).

```
from collections import defaultdict
slack_dict = defaultdict(list)
slack_dict[u'djin_acontentmgmt_sample'] = [
    {'color': u'blue', 'status': 'SUCCESS', 'region': u'virginia', 'env': u'int', 'job_no': '122'}
]
with open('slack_dict', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(slack_dict).encode('UTF-8'))

with open('slack_dict', 'r') as f:
    print f.read()

# defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'djin_acontentmgmt_sample': [{'color': u'blue', 'status': 'SUCCESS', 'region': u'virginia', 'env': u'int', 'job_no': '122'}]})
```

Are you trying to eliminate the 'u' markers, e.g., to write json text? In that case, you could try this:

```
import json
with open('slack_dict', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(slack_dict, f)
    # equivalent to f.write(json.dumps(slack_dict))

with open('slack_dict', 'r') as f:
    print f.read()

# {"djin_acontentmgmt_sample": [{"color": "blue", "status": "SUCCESS", "region": "virginia", "env": "int", "job_no": "122"}]}
```

Comment: Consider using `json.dump(slack_dict,f)` instead of `f.write(json.dumps(slack_dict))`.

Comment: Good idea, I've added that.